# Apache ignite problem with running two clusters (with one node) on two servers

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

I tried to configure two Ignite.NET Standalone Nodes on two different servers (as server nodes) with authentication. For the authentication it requires persistent storage be enabled for at least one data region and to activate a cluster. I configured the first node and activate the cluster. When I moved to second node and configure it exactly as the first node it somehow added it to the first luster with no discovery configuration. in the first node I changed the password of the ignite user and when I tried to connect to the second node with the default password it rejected me and accept only the first node password. my question is how the second node know this password and joined to the cluster automatically?

IP addresses of the nodes `x.y.z.220 x.y.z.221`

Apache.ignite.exe.config:

```
      <igniteConfiguration xmlns="http://ignite.apache.org/schema/dotnet/IgniteConfigurationSection">
             <cacheConfiguration>
                <cacheConfiguration>
                    <name>default</name>
                </cacheConfiguration>
            </cacheConfiguration>
            <clientConnectorConfiguration type="ClientConnectorConfiguration">
                <port>6379</port>
            </clientConnectorConfiguration>
            <dataStorageConfiguration>
                <defaultDataRegionConfiguration>
                        <name>Default_Region</name>
                        <persistenceEnabled>true</persistenceEnabled>
                </defaultDataRegionConfiguration>
            </dataStorageConfiguration>
            <authenticationEnabled>true</authenticationEnabled>
        </igniteConfiguration>
```

Comment: Multicast discovery is used by default, so nodes see each other on the same subnet. Are you trying to form two separate clusters? Why?

Comment: Thanks @PavelTupitsyn! and yes i try to form two separate clusters because i want to add a generic installation of ignite to my product installation (the same  installation on every physical server) and i see that for cluster i have to be specific (configure a list of IP's...ports) and i want to avoid it. so i implemented master-slave and exchanging of server node by myself and save the current master hostname in the DB. so every client node can look in the DB and ask for connection. do you familiar with other way to make it generic and client can connect to available server node? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ignite uses [Multicast discovery](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/tcp-ip-discovery) by default, and nodes within the same subnet find each other automatically.

To avoid this, configure an IP finder. You can use loopback address to make sure the node won't connect to other nodes outside of the current machine:

```
    <discoverySpi type="TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <ipFinder type="TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder">
            <endpoints>
                <string>127.0.0.1:47500</string>
            </endpoints>
        </ipFinder>
    </discoverySpi>
```